# Possible to use Microsoft Azure SQL and Azure Storage in combination?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am building a web application that I want to take advantage of both Azure SQL as well as Azure Storage Tables in combination. I plan to write a data-layer with two modules. One that handles Azure Storage and another that handles Azure SQL. has this ever been done before? I've been unable to find even a mention of the internet.

Comment: I will ask you the opposite, why wouldn't it be possible? What problem are you expecting to face?

Comment: its not like there is an SDK call to do that, but why it wouldnt be possible is beyond me

Comment: Sure.  Also note that you can read BLOB storage from TSQL in Azure SQL Database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your replies. I'm just going to build it out and see what obstacles I hit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work. You may need to think how you are going to keep them in sync (say if one of the writes failed - this is cloud and things break at scale).

Table storage is great if you have one key to put data in (user profiles). You can't perform aggregate queries across it so the sql backend would be useful.

Comment: I am not sure what this attempts to answer, or why you think the OP needs to keep ATS and the database in sync. Also, what exactly can't you query from ATS?

Comment: You can't easily perform aggregate queries across table storage.

Comment: One of the two writes will fail at some point and then you have a synchronization problem.

Comment: Table storage has a primary key and a secondary key. That's as far as lookups go (unless you want to table scan for everything).

Comment: Chriseyre2000, thanks. Yes, it's true, querying is much harder on ATS than it is on SQL. I wonder if there is anything close to an equivalent of SQL Manager Enterprise...but for ATS.

Comment: Chriseyre2000, What ways do you know of, to synch between ATS and SQL? Are there any Microsoft tools that do this?

Comment: It's been a couple of years  since I last looked at this. There are a number of third party query tools for azure storage. There is no point in making something as powerful as  Enterprise Manager for a key value store. Syncing them is custom code (and will be slow as you can only read a small number of rows at a time. You need to decide which is the master and copy from that. Table storage is a cheap per user cache.